# sed command to batch change fill and stroke of an SVG

Tags: svg, batch-processing, fill, inkscape, stroke

I have a folder with around 300 SVG icons. It is all black. I would like to change the fill and stroke colours of all icons ( to shades of blue). It is a very hard job to do 300 through Inkscape. I saw some examples of using `sed` command to do it as a batch. But none suited my requirement.Can someone help me with this ? I am also open to other options. I tried IcoMoon as a GUI option, but not sure how to change the colour in it as a batch.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly the structure of your SVG, but I will suppose that you use icons like font-awesome ones (SVG format).

You say that the original color is black, so here we have multiples cases :

1. there is no fill and stroke attribute in the XML
2. the fill and stroke attribute can be with the values "black" or "currentValue"

The script bellow takes the two cases in consideration :

```
#/bin/sh
COLOR=yellow
sed -i -E 's/fill\="[^"]+"//g; s/stroke\="[^"]+"//g' *.svg
sed -i "s/<path/<path fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
```

you've just to set the destination color into the COLOR variable, and don't forget to run the script inside your folder.

I tested the script for the font-awesome SVG icons, and it works.

Let me know if it works for you.

EDIT :
For the ionicons (outline), try the script bellow :

```
#/bin/sh
COLOR=yellow
sed -i -E 's/fill\="[^"]+"//g; s/stroke\="[^"]+"//g' *.svg
sed -i "s/<path/<path fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<rect/<rect fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<polygon/<polygon fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<circle/<circle fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<ellipse/<ellipse fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i "s/<polyline/<polyline fill=\"$COLOR\" stroke=\"$COLOR\"/g" *.svg
sed -i -E "s/stroke\:[^\;]+/stroke\:$COLOR/g" *.svg
sed -i -E "s/fill\:\#[0-9]+/fill\:$COLOR/g" *.svg
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using `outline` version of Ionicons v5.0 https://ionicons.com/. I hope the script will work with that. T

Comment: I need to save these two lines as `script.sh` and then run `./script.sh` , right ?

Comment: I get t `$ sudo ./script.sh
sudo: ./script.sh: command not found`

Comment: in fact, i've just edited my answer for the ionicons (outline), try the second script.

Comment: to run the script 1- you have to save it to script.sh, 2 - allow the execution permission (run the command "chmod a+x script.sh"), 3 - then run it ./script.sh

Comment: I've just tested it for version 5.0.0, and I think that it works for all the icons (1227 items) NB: I've just edited the script to take all cases.

Comment: the first script worked well on outline. But when I tried the latest one, stroke went yellow instead of green I have set. Please see https://i.imgur.com/W28H2AN.png . Thanks.

Comment: I think that you forgot to change the COLOR variable (from COLOR=yellow to COLOR=green) for the latest script, can you check the COLOR variable?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo from my end. I kept colour as yellow, but made a typo in hex value in 2nd line from last. I need to replace yellow with stroke colour ? Thanks.

Comment: yes, you have to change the yellow with your desired color